# Change input text bg color with radio button

Tags: javascript

i need help to change an input text background color depending on which radio button is selected. If radio button 1 is selected the background of the input text goes green and if radio button 2 is selected it goes red, and if radio button 3 is selected hide the input text. So far i managed to hide the input text when radio 3 is selected. This is a work assignment so i need to use javascript only. Thank you.

```js
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<td><input type="radio" name="row-2" value="positive"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="row-2" value="negative"></td>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction2()" name="row-2" value="neutral"  checked></td>
<td><div id="myDIV2"><input type="text"  name="row-2"></div></td>
```

Comment: you need to test against the current value of the radio group, not if myDIV2's display

Comment: I will leave you with this https://jsfiddle.net/0k61pdec/ (check your console) but I think that is more than enough to help you figure out your homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. Don't forget that if you're going to call this function on `onclick` you have to provide it for all the elements you want it to be run for.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  let selectedRadioValue = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
  let textBox = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  switch (selectedRadioValue) {
    case "positive":
      textBox.style.visibility = 'visible';
      textBox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
    case "negative":
      textBox.style.visibility = 'visible';
      textBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
    case "neutral":
      textBox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      break;
  }
}
/*Calling `myFunction2()` below to set the initial state of the textbox.
Do this because you provided the checked attribute to the `neutral` radio.*/
myFunction2();
```

```html
<td><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction2()" name="row-2" value="positive"></td>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction2()" name="row-2" value="negative"></td>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction2()" name="row-2" value="neutral"  checked></td>
<td><div id="myDIV2"><input type="text" name="row-2"></div></td>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for.